# If i am using re.finditer(), how can I limit the number of occurrences in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a python script that needs to go through a file and find certain paragraphs. I am able to successfully match the pattern using regex, however, the number of times that same paragraph occurs is more than 1. I simply need the first occurrence of the paragraph to be printed out.

Is there anything that I could add to my regular expression that would only return the first occurance.

This is my regex expression thus far...  `pattern = re.compile(//#|//\s#).+[\S\s]` , then i did `matches = pattern.finditer(file_name)` , lastly i traversed through a for loop and printed `print(i.group())`. Note: the reason why i did finditer() instead of findall() is because i need it to be printed out as a string rather then a list.

Any guidance as to how I can tweak my current approach to only yield the first matched paragraph would be great!

Comment: Please post your code as [example], so we can reproduce and tweak your code.

Comment: Regarding also [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72888928/matching-a-block-of-lines-with-python-regex#comment128741620_72888928): Somethiing like [this using `re.search`?](https://tio.run/##zVE9C8IwFJzNrwjpktCSDm6CdHIoVCed2ipSQ5shH7xE1F8fW0Gros7e9Li7dzze2YvvjJ6GIJU14DEIhEC04oznGAjNZts0rVwW8bjSGYsJQl44v3MeegMlaRq9AleaoMnAPyYclc4ogU8GDvWov@EjP0bg8iBcA9J6aXT9xHPOx9Uf6V@UP72XMISQGjoQ3Ik9NB29tZLg@/uTQVpuinVe5KtFb7cgtaeKt2COljIWwhU) Try pattern [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/walf0F/1).

Answer (score 1):

You might simply use `.search` rather than `.finditer`, example

```
import re
text = 'A1B2C3'
pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9])')
found = pattern.search(text).group()
print(found)  # 1
print(isinstance(found,str))  # True
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, when i try to use .search it now only outputs the first line of the paragraph and not the entire paragraph as a whole. Could this problem be solved by iterating through a loop and if so, how may i go about doing that?